# How to avoid header while exporting BigQuery table in to Google Storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have developed below code which is helping to export BigQuery table in to Google storage bucket. I want to merge files into single file with out header, so that next processes will use file with out any issue.

```
    def export_bq_table_to_gcs(self, table_name):
        client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)

        print("Exporting table {}".format(table_name))
        dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_name,
                                     project=project_name)
        dataset = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_ref)
        table_ref = dataset.table(table_name)
        size_bytes = client.get_table(table_ref).num_bytes

        # For tables bigger than 1GB uses Google auto split, otherwise export is forced in a single file.
        if size_bytes > 10 ** 9:
            destination_uris = [
                      'gs://{}/{}{}*.csv'.format(bucket_name,
                                       f'{table_name}_temp', uid)]
        else:
            destination_uris = [
                      'gs://{}/{}{}.csv'.format(bucket_name,
                                      f'{table_name}_temp', uid)]

        extract_job = client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uris)  # API request
        result = extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

        if result.state != 'DONE' or result.errors:
            raise Exception('Failed extract job {} for table {}'.format(result.job_id, table_name))
        else:
            print('BQ table(s) export completed successfully')
        storage_client = storage.Client(project=gs_project_name)
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(gs_bucket_name)
        blob_list = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f'{table_name}_temp')
        print('Merging shard files into single file')
        bucket.blob(f'{table_name}.csv').compose(blob_list)
```

Can you please help me to find a way to skip header.

Thanks,

Raghunath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can avoid header by using jobConfig to set the print_header parameter to False. Sample code

```
job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig(print_header=False)
extract_job = client.extract_table(table_ref, destination_uris,
                                   job_config=job_config)
```

Thanks

Comment: how to do it in Nodejs?

Comment: I used print_header=false in Nodejs options and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skipLeadingRows` (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#externalDataConfiguration.googleSheetsOptions.skipLeadingRows)

Comment: I am exporting BQ table, I guess you shared option which is can be used while importing CSV to BQ table. Let me know if I misunderstand